# openfire REST API plugin return 404 not found

Tags: xmpp, openfire

I'm using openfire version 4.0.2 and had download and upload REST API plugin to my openfire server. It looks like the plugin has been successfully installed but not working, please refer to the screenshot below. I download the plugin from https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins.jsp. What i want to do is to call the rest api url in node application and be able to do CRUD on user account. I still not implement this in node application but trying to test the url using postman but the response return 404 as in the screenshot below.

**Openfire plugins**

[image: plugin]

**Openfire server setting**

[image: setting]

**Response from postman**

[image: postman]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The url is wrong. The true url is http://x.x.x.x:9090/plugins/restapi/v1/users. No /api/.

Comment: For further help, check the documentation: https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/restapi/readme.html

Comment: Ok. Appreciate your help. Thanks